# Ограничить изменение размера элементов

Tags: javascript, resize

Есть функция, которая собирает элементы и их координаты:

```
function coordinateCollector(id, item) {

    var leftSide = item.offset().left;
    var rightSide = item.offset().left + item.width();
    var topSide = item.offset().top;

    playlistStorage[id] = {
        left: leftSide,
        right: rightSide,
        top: topSide
    };
}
```

и функция изменения размера:

```
    function resize() {
    $('.movable-playlist')
        .mousedown(function (e) {

            resizableSausage = $(this);

            var elWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));

            if (e.offsetX >= elWidth - 5 && e.offsetX <= elWidth) {
                rightClientX = elWidth - e.offsetX;
                resize_target = e.target;
                resizeStateRight = true;
                clientXforResize = e.clientX;
                initialWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
                disable = true;
                drag();
            }

            if (e.offsetX >= 0 && e.offsetX <= 5) {
                leftClienX = e.offsetX;
                resize_target = e.target;
                resizeStateLeft = true;
                clientXforResize = e.clientX;
                initialLeft = parseInt($(this).css('left'));
                initialWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
                disable = true;
                drag();
            }
        })
        .mouseup(function (e) {
            resizeStateRight = false;

            var elWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));

            if (e.offsetX >= elWidth - 5 && e.offsetX <= elWidth) {
                resizeStateRight = false;
                resize_target = null;
                disable = false;
                drag();
            }

            if (e.offsetX >= 0 && e.offsetX <= 5) {
                resizeStateLeft = false;
                resize_target = null;
                disable = false;
                drag();
            }
        });

    $(document)
        .mousemove(function (e) {

            for (var prop in playlistStorage) {
                var itemsInStorage = playlistStorage[prop];
            }

            var widthOffset;

            if (resizeStateRight == true && e.clientX <= timelineRigft - rightClientX) {

                widthOffset = clientXforResize - e.clientX;

                $(resize_target).css({
                    'width': (initialWidth - widthOffset) + 'px'
                });

                $('.pl-popup').hide();

            }

            if (resizeStateLeft == true && e.clientX >= timelineLeft + leftClienX && $(resizableSausage).offset().left >= itemsInStorage.right) {

                widthOffset = clientXforResize - e.clientX;

                $(resize_target).css({
                    'width': (initialWidth + widthOffset) + 'px',
                    'left': (initialLeft - widthOffset) + 'px'
                });

                $('.pl-popup').hide();

            }
        })
        .mouseup(function () {
            resizeStateRight = false;
            resizeStateLeft = false;
            disable = false;
            drag();
        });
}
```

Делаю перебор координат элементов циклом

```
for (var prop in playlistStorage) {
                var itemsInStorage = playlistStorage[prop];
            }
```

Пытаюсь ограничить изменение размеров элементов при столконовении с другим элементом через добавление в условие сравнение координат элемента изменяющего размер и элемента-препятсвие:

```
$(resizableSausage).offset().left >= itemsInStorage.right
```

Поведение элементов становится мало предсказуемым...

Comment: Правильнее было бы обрабатывать элементы функцией Array.prototype.map()

Comment: @Oceinic был бы очень рад небольшому примеру, спасибо.